# Maven RPM Packaging After *.jar creation

Tags: maven, build, package, installation, rpm

I researched everywhere, but could not find answer. My problem is that I would like to create my *.jar file with all its dependencies using the usual mvn install scheme. But once the *.jar is created, I like to package it using Mojo RPM plugin.

The problem is that Mojo RPM plugin is executed during mvn install lifecycle. However the *.jar is not created until after the install phase is complete. So when the rpm plugin runs, it will not have any *.jar to install.

How can we build, install the jar and then package it into an rpm using Mojo RPM plugin?

Comment: The JAR is packaged by `maven-jar-plugin`, or `maven-assembly-plugin` if you're doing a jar-with-dependencies, in the `package` phase, normally. Not the `install` phase. Can you post your current config, what is wrong with it and what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: @Tunaki What I want to achieve is that once I generate the .jar file Id lilke to package that into an rpm file. I am not able to do that using mojo rpm

Comment: What's wrong with the sample there http://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/usage.html? Did you hit an issue? The goals bind by default to `package`, after `default-package` where the JAR was created so everything is alright.